# Ubuntu 18.04 HP Laptop Realtek 8821CE WiFi Adapter not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, adapter

I’m a brand new Linux user, made the switch from Windows 10 last night. I have a HP 15-db0030AU laptop that has a Realtek 8821ce wireless lan 802.11ac pci-e NIC.

Currently, the wifi section in the settings app shows that no “No Wi-Fi Adapter Found”. I have been tethering via USB to my phone.

After running commands in the terminal while following a tutorial, my adapter is being recognised and is listed, but it is not operational.

Does anyone now how to fix this?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I have a desktop with the same WiFi adapter (8821CE) which wasn't getting detected on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the driver for 8821CE following the instructions here https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce  (this needs dkms). Everything works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you get no WiFi adapter found in Ubuntu 18.04, run this code in your terminal:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Then reboot your lap, check wifi signal. If it doesn’t show, go to Unity Dash and look for Software & Updates, then Next is to go in Additional Drivers tab and select the propriety driver and click on Apply Changes.

[image: screenshot]

If you notice weak signal, try:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1
```

and see if it is better, if not do:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

Comment: The OP has an 8821CE Realtek card. Your answer seems to be valid for another one (8723de).

Answer (score 0):

I have a different fix that worked with that specific Realtek 8821, after weeks of dropping out and having to reset network adaptor - Windows+X, then device manager, then network adaptor - right click, one of the tabs has an option for power saving - uncheck this box.  It looks like the update has set the network adaptor to power saving, so every time you stop using it for 2 minutes, or use the machine on battery, it drops out.  Did this fix yesterday and no issues since

Jim