# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 18.04, Plug in a dongle to use

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

My Bluetooth is not working in my ubuntu 18.04(I recently installed it). I have tried almost all answers on StackExchange, but no use.

Here are some commands that might help you understand the problem.

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
lines 1-4/4 (END)
```

I know it can be started by
`systemctl start bluetooth` but it is of no use, as it does not change any thing except the status.

And

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
```

It does not do any thing except a blank cursor which I have to cancel manually.

I also have installed bluez as someone said in any answer. Version is

```
$ dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1
```

If I start bluetooth service by `$ systemctl start bluetooth` then `bluetoothctl` shows following.

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# power
Missing on/off argument
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

But I can see a small bluetooth ugly symbol at top(Maybe because of bluez), but turing it on pops up a window as following
[image]

Please help me solve this problem.

#### Edit

Also 1 more command might help you, after starting bluetooth, I typed this too

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ce
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:1055 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Edit:

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

### Edit2

[image]

### Edit 3

```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ lsmod | grep -i rtl
rtl8821ce            1794048  0
cfg80211              712704  1 rtl8821ce
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install blueman` and then `sudo apt-get bluez` then reboot.

Comment: Already did that, nothing happened.

Comment: Try `rfkill list` and post the output for us.

Comment: @darth_epoxy added the output

Comment: Hmm, if you go to **Startup Applications** from the Show Applications menu do you see the Blueman Applet or any other Bluetooth apps/modules there? Also, typing `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth` once should prevent you from having to use the **start** command after every boot.

Comment: In *Startup Applications* I see *Blueman applet* only. I ran `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth` but no use. After running this command, I ran this to check but no use.
```
(base) ahmad@ahmad-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx:~$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it's the driver then, please investigate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080561/ubuntu-18-04-hp-laptop-realtek-8821ce-wifi-adapter-not-working as your 8821CE is a combined WiFi/Bluetootch network adapter.

Comment: @darth_epoxy, I already added the drivers for this using software and updates, isn't it sufficient though? Thanks for the link though, I will try it.

Comment: Remove the donlge, reboot and after logging in immediately open a terminal and try `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723ce && sudo modprobe rtl8723ce` then see if you get a different response.

Comment: How to remove dongle? Everything is built-in laptop, I havent attached any external dongle.

Comment: Anyways, doing that command gives this output `modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723ce not found.`

Comment: Your questions reads "Plug in a dongle to use" but let's move on. We need to find the module name so we can try the modprobe method. Type `lsmod | grep -i rtl
` and see if one looks like it is meant for your 8723 network adapter.

Comment: Added the results of `lsmod | grep -i rtl`

Comment: Oh my bad c&p, use `sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ce && sudo modprobe rtl8821ce` then.

Comment: This restarted my Wifi, but Bluetooth still not working. and for this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080561/ubuntu-18-04-hp-laptop-realtek-8821ce-wifi-adapter-not-working link, the github link given in it is not working.

Comment: See if you have multiple modules in which case you might need to blacklist some `lsmod | grep -i blu` and then check again for errors `dmesg | grep -i blue` and post relevant info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112413/discussion-between-ahmad-anis-and-darth-epoxy).